# Not able to select anything from drop down list after disabling the keypad in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using the following code to disable keypad when user tap outside of the textfield. I am able to disable the keypad, but the problem is not able to select anything from drop down list. Please suggest me.

ViewDidLoad:

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
 [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tap];

 [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
 [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
 [textField3 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we haven't seen your code for the "dropdown", but I can guess you want to make it the first responder manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.tap is nil in the instance of the code you have typed, so when you come to remove it it just fails silently. You are creating the gesture recognizer as tap, not self.tap.

Comment: i have changed to [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tap]; Now i can able to select but second time when i tap (means after removing tap) keypad is not disabled.

Comment: Can you post more code please, I need to see when/where the tap code is created

Comment: Ah, I see it's in view did load. You should add [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; when you show the keyboard, not in view did load. As you're doing it in viewDidLoad instead it's only getting added the once, and then you remove it on dismissKeyboard

Comment: In your view did load:

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

Comment: - (void)keyboardDidShow { [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; }